# On analogy between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb F_q[x]$

Tags: prime-numbers, finite-fields, exponentiation, irreducible-polynomials, finite-rings

There are objects and operations analogous between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb F_q[x]$. For example primes in $\Bbb Z$ and irreducibles in $\Bbb F_q[x]$ are analogous and so is multiplication operation.

Consider objects $\Bbb Z/p$ for $p$ a prime and $\Bbb F_q[x]/f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is irreducible.

For $a\in\Bbb Z/p,b\in\Bbb Z/(p-1)$ we can define $a^b\in\Bbb Z/p$.

Similarly for $a(x)\in\Bbb F_q[x]/f(x),b(x)\in\Bbb F_q[x]/(f(x)-1)$ can we define $a(x)^{b(x)}\in\Bbb F_q[x]/f(x)$?

Comment: The proper analogy is that if $R=\Bbb{Z}/p$, so $|R|=p$, then we can define $a^b\in R$ where $a\in R$ and $b\in\Bbb{Z}/(|R|-1)$. Similarly with $R=\Bbb{F}_q[x]/f(x)$, so $|R|=q^{\deg f(x)}$ we can define $a^b\in R$ when $a\in R$ and $b\in\Bbb{Z}/(|R|-1)$. IOW the exponent is always an integer, and can be viewed as coming from a residue class ring if we are careful. For example, it plays out as above only when $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen given $g,h,f\in\Bbb F_p[x]$ is it easy to find $z$ is $g^z=h\bmod f$ in $(\log deg(f))^c$ operations?

Comment: I mean $(deg(f)\log p)^c$ operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Fermat's little theorem in this setting, and it says the following: if $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of degree $d$, then

$$g(x)^{p^d} \equiv g(x) \bmod f(x).$$

So exponents are well-defined $\bmod p^d - 1$ (the order of the cyclic group $\left( \mathbb{F}_p[x]/f(x) \right)^{\times}$). In the analogy between the integers and $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, exponents stay integers: they play a totally different role than bases.

Comment: Is there a multivariate generalization of this?

Answer (score 1):

For $a,b\in\Bbb Z/p$, we *cannot* define $a^b\in\Bbb Z/p$: we can only do so if we take $b\in\Bbb Z/(p-1)$.

For example, $2^7 \equiv 2 \bmod 7$ but $2^{0} \equiv 1 \bmod 7$ even though $ 7 \equiv 0 \bmod 7$.

Comment: So is it true if $a,b\in\Bbb Z$, then $a^{b\bmod (p-1)}\bmod p=a^b\bmod p$?